# Does Chrome not support audio/ogg; codecs=opus?

Tags: google-chrome, web-audio-api, mediarecorder

I have researched this an according to `MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported` Chromium does not support audio/ogg; codecs=opus. Does anyone know if there is an alternative to use with MediaRecorder or if Chrome is planning to add this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Chrome only supports "audio/webm; codecs=opus".

Comment: It should. I did play with it a little while ago and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

From the list of supported formats [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42307926/2441655), it appears it does not.

However, there are some libraries that help you record to alternative formats, as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57837816/2441655