# Updating objectURL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser

Suppose I am receiving data from a video chat and I need to add the data to the video element in the HTML page.

So here is the code:

```
var payload = [];   // This array keeps updating, since it is getting the data from the network using media stream.
var remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
var buffer = new Blob([], { type: "video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1,opus" });
var url = URL.createObjectURL(buffer);
remoteVideo.src = url;
```

Now, I am getting data in the buffer. How do I update the url i have created instead of creating a new one again to view the video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might not need to update the url at all using [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource),the process goes like this:

1. Create a `MediaSource` Object.
2. Create an object URL from the `MediaSource` using createObjectURl
3. Set the video's src to the object URL
4. listen to`sourceopen` event and when it occurs, create a `SourceBuffer`  instance.
5. Use `SourceBuffer.appendBuffer()` to add all of your chunks to the video.

But pay close attention to `MediaSource` limitations and considerations.

**EDIT:**

I found this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333767/html5-video-streaming-video-with-blob-urls/50354182) which explains the process described above more precisely and also points out the considerations you should take, and also an example.