# Google Cloud Speech-to-Text: "INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid recognition 'config': bad encoding.." codec audio encoding error

Tags: getusermedia, google-cloud-speech

I'm recording short audio files (a few seconds) in Chrome using `mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`, saving the file to Firebase Storage, and then trying to send the files to Google Cloud Speech-to-Text from a Firebase Cloud Function. I'm getting back this error message:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid recognition 'config': bad encoding.
```

Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/error-messages#invalid_recognition_config_bad_encoding) says that this error message means

> Your audio data might not be encoded correctly or is encoded with a
>   codec different than what you've declared in the RecognitionConfig.
>   Check the audio input and make sure that you've set the encoding field
>   correctly.

In the browser I set up the microphone:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
.then(stream => {

var options = {
   audioBitsPerSecond : 128000,
   mimeType : 'audio/webm;codecs=opus'
};

const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
mediaRecorder.start();
...
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739837/all-mime-types-supported-by-mediarecorder-in-firefox-and-chrome) Chrome only supports two codecs:

```
audio/webm
audio/webm;codecs=opus
```

Actually, that's one media format and one codec. [This blog post](https://blog.addpipe.com/audio-constraints-getusermedia/) also says that Chrome only supports the Opus codec.

I set up my Firebase Cloud Function:

```js
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

// Creates a client
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

const gcsUri = 'gs://my-app.appspot.com/my-file';
const encoding = 'Opus';
const sampleRateHertz = 128000;
const languageCode = 'en-US';

const config = {
   encoding: encoding,
   sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
   languageCode: languageCode,
};
const audio = {
   uri: gcsUri,
};

const request = {
   config: config,
   audio: audio,
};

// Detects speech in the audio file
return response = client.recognize(request) // square brackets in ES6 construct an array
.then(function(response) {
console.log(response);
...
```

The audio encoding matches between the browser and the Google Speech-to-Text request. Why does Google Speech tell me that the audio encoding is bad?

I also tried using the default options in the browser, with the same error message:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
.then(stream => {

const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
mediaRecorder.start();
```

In the Firebase Cloud Function I tried leaving out the line `const encoding = 'Opus';`, which resulted in an error `encoding is not defined`. I tried this line `const encoding = '';` which resulted in the `INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid recognition 'config': bad encoding..` error.

I'm getting a [similar error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60748633/ibm-watson-speech-to-text-unable-to-transcode-data-stream-audio-webm-audio-x) from IBM Watson Speech-to-Text. The file plays back without a problem.

Comment: I got similar issue with google voice to text using python SDK. I face this issue randomly but often (1 of 5 in average). But if I call the API twice with the same exact audio file whenever this error occurs, well on the second time it works..