# IBM Watson Speech-to-Text "unable to transcode data stream audio/webm -> audio/x-float-array" media MIME types

Tags: audio, ibm-watson, speech-to-text, getusermedia, ibm-cloud-speech

I'm recording short audio files (a few seconds) in Chrome using `mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`, saving the file to Firebase Storage, and then trying to send the files to IBM Watson Speech-to-Text. I'm getting back this error message:

```
unable to transcode data stream audio/webm -> audio/x-float-array
```

In the browser I set up the microphone:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
.then(stream => {

var options = {
   audioBitsPerSecond : 128000,
   mimeType : 'audio/webm'
};

const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
mediaRecorder.start();
...
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60747880/google-cloud-speech-to-text-invalid-argument-invalid-recognition-config-ba) Chrome only supports two media types

```
audio/webm
audio/webm;codecs=opus
```

I tried both.

Here's what I sent to IBM Watson:

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:my-api-key" \
--header "Content-Type: audio/webm" \
--data-binary "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-app.appspot.com/my-file" \
--url "https://api.us-south.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/01010101/v1/recognize"
```

The list of [supported MIME types](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-audio-formats#formats) includes `webm` and `webm;codecs=opus`.

I tried recording and sending a `ogg` format file, and got the same error message:

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:my-api-key" \
--header "Content-Type: audio/ogg" \
--data-binary @/Users/TDK/LanguageTwo/public/1.ogg \
--url "https://api.us-south.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/01010101/v1/recognize"
```

I tried IBM's sample audio file and it worked perfectly:

```
"transcript": "several tornadoes touched down as a line of severe thunderstorms swept through Colorado on Sunday "
```

I'm getting a [similar error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60747880/google-cloud-speech-to-text-invalid-argument-invalid-recognition-config-ba) from Google Cloud Speech-to-Text.

Comment: Did you figured it out how to send correct data to IBM Watson ?

Comment: curl -X POST -u "apikey:$apikey" --header "Content-Type: audio/mp3" --data-binary @"$1" "$url/v1/recognize?timestamps=true&max_alternatives=3"

Answer (score 0):

Create a bash script called `watsonstt.sh` (I recommend saving in `~/bin/`), paste in contents below, replace `apikey`, `url`, and `savepath` variable content with your own and call the script as the comment recommends, including quotes for the single argument (to deal with spaces).

API credentials are supplied within the 'Manage' tab of the IBM Watson cloud web interface at time of writing and you need to sign up with credit/debit card details.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# call this script with one argument for posix file path parameter in quotes e.g.: 
# watsonstt.sh "/user/name/file.mp3"

# 500 mins per month for free
# https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/curl.html?curl#get-token

apikey=XXXXXXXXXXXX
url=YYYYYYYYYY
savepath=~/Desktop/${1##*/}.txt

curl -X POST -u "apikey:$apikey" --header "Content-Type: audio/${1##*.}" --data-binary @"$1" "$url/v1/recognize?timestamps=true&max_alternatives=3" -o "${savepath}"
```