# Can Google Chrome record an audio file for Google Cloud Speech-to-Text without changing the media type or encoding?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, google-cloud-speech

My app records an audiofile from the microphone in the browser, typically Chrome; sends it to Firebase Storage; then a Firebase Cloud Function sends the audiofile to Google Cloud Speech-to-Text. Everything works with IBM Cloud Speech-to-Text. With Google Cloud Speech-to-Text it works if I send the `audio/flac` sample file "several tornadoes touched down as a line of severe thunderstorms swept through Colorado on Sunday". But when I send an audiofile recorded in the browser I get back an error message:

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

Here's the browser code. The audio settings are at the top: `audio/webm;codecs=opus` and `48000` bits per second. This is the only [media file format and encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739837/all-mime-types-supported-by-mediarecorder-in-firefox-and-chrome/42307926#42307926) that Chrome supports.

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
    .then(stream => {

      var options = {
        audioBitsPerSecond: 48000, // switch to 8000 on slow connections?
        mimeType: 'audio/webm;codecs=opus' // only options on Chrome
      };

      const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
      mediaRecorder.start();

      const audioChunks = [];

      mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
        audioChunks.push(event.data);
      });

      mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
        const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);

        firebase.storage().ref('Users/' + $scope.user.uid + '/Pronunciation_Test').put(audioBlob) // upload to Firebase Storage
        .then(function(snapshot) {
          firebase.storage().ref(snapshot.ref.location.path).getDownloadURL()   // get downloadURL
          .then(function(url) {
            firebase.firestore().collection('Users').doc($scope.user.uid).collection("Pronunciation_Test").doc('downloadURL').set({downloadURL: url})
            .then(function() {
              console.log("Document successfully written!");
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            });
          })
          .catch(error => console.error(error))
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));

        // play back the audio blob
        const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
        const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
        audio.play();
      });

      setTimeout(() => {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
      }, 3000);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error.name + ": " + error.message);
    });
```

Firebase Storage converts the audiofile from `webm/opus` to `application/octet-streaming`.

Here's my Firebase Cloud Function that gets an audiofile from Firebase Storage and sends it to Google Cloud Speech-to-Text.

```js
exports.Google_Speech_to_Text = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}/Pronunciation_Test/downloadURL').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    // Imports the Google Cloud client library
    const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

    // Creates a client
    const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

    const downloadURL = change.after.data().downloadURL;

    const gcsUri = downloadURL;
    const encoding = 'application/octet-stream';
    const sampleRateHertz = 48000;
    const languageCode = 'en-US';

    const config = {
      encoding: encoding,
      sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
      languageCode: languageCode,
    };
    const audio = {
      uri: gcsUri,
    };

    const request = {
      config: config,
      audio: audio,
    };

    // Detects speech in the audio file
    return response = client.recognize(request)
    .then(function(response) {
      const [responseArray] = response;
      const transcription = responseArray.results
      .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
      .join('\n');
      console.log(`Transcription: `, transcription);
    })
    .catch((err) => { console.error(err); });
  }); // close Google_Speech_to_Text
```

Here's the list of [supported media formats and encodings](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding) for Google Cloud Speech-to-Text:

```
MP3
FLAC
LINEAR16
MULAW
AMR
AMR_WB  
OGG_OPUS
SPEEX_WITH_HEADER_BYTE
```

`webm/opus` and `application/octet-streaming` aren't on the list.

Am I missing something or is it impossible to record an audiofile in Chrome, save it in Firebase Storage, and then send it to Google Cloud Speech-to-Text? It seems strange that Google products wouldn't work together. Do I have to recode the audiofile with `ffmpeg` before I send it to Google Cloud Speech-to-Text?

Comment: have you checked the result for 'OGG_OPUS'? Maybe it works, same format different container. If not, I guess you have to do some preprocessing; as you documented those are the only encodings that your request will accept.

Comment: Yep, that's been my experience - that Speech to text & Dialogflow codecs are not compatible with the MediaRecorder codecs. I've spent days going down this path, now I'm going back to ScriptProcessorNode (depecrated APIs) in order to harvest the raw data from the audio channel for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the file type before uploading it
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

```
mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
    //const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);
    const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, {type : 'webm/opus'});
    // try to change 'webm/opus' to something supported by google.
```

Comment: Could you provide a full working example? `new Blob(audioChunks, {type : 'webm/opus'});` does not change the encoding of the audio