# Record as Ogg using MediaRecorder in Chrome

Tags: javascript, mediarecorder

Is there a way we could record ogg format in Chrome while working with MediaRecorder ? I believe, Chrome by default supports WebM. Following is what I do

```
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(stream => {
        rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);

        rec.ondataavailable = e => {
            audioChunks.push(e.data);
            if (rec.state == "inactive")
            {
                let blob = new Blob(audioChunks, { 'type': 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
            }
        };

    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nop, not really. Ended up converting from Server end.

Answer (score 12):

From the list of supported formats [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42307926/2441655), it appears it does not.

However, here are some libraries that help you record to alternative formats:

#### 1) Opus Media Recorder: https://github.com/kbumsik/opus-media-recorder

> Formats (Container.Codec): Ogg.Opus, WebM.Opus, WAV.PCM
>   Browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge

Note: Does not let you change the sampling rate for Opus recording from the default of 48000hz. (For example, this means its output can't directly be submitted to [DialogFlow](https://dialogflow.com), since it [requires Opus audio to have a sample rate of 16000hz](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/api/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.AudioEncoding.html).)

#### 2) Opus Recorder: https://github.com/chris-rudmin/opus-recorder

> Formats: Ogg.Opus, WAV.PCM
>   Browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Edge

#### 3) LibFlac: https://github.com/mmig/libflac.js

> Formats: FLAC.FLAC
>   Browsers: (unknown, but probably same as the above)

See the [speech-to-flac example](https://github.com/mmig/speech-to-flac) for how to use with microphone input.

#### 4) WebAudioRecorder: https://github.com/higuma/web-audio-recorder-js

> Formats: Ogg.Vorbis, MP3.MP3, WAV.PCM
>   Browsers: (unknown, but probably same as the above)

#### 5) Libraries augmenting MediaRecorder with WAV/PCM support

A: https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC (recorderType: RecordRTC.StereoAudioRecorder)
B: https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder (mimeType: "audio/wav" or "audio/pcm")

#### 6) Manual WAV.PCM encoding

For WAV.PCM, the format is simple enough you don't necessarily need a library. If you prefer a "lower level" approach, you can look through the examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54213814/2441655

Answer (score -1):

You just missed to start the recoder, like: rec.start(timeslice)

A code like this works, I added a player every time we record audio, so we can play and verify it recorded.

```
var audioChunks = [];
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
.then(stream => {
    rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    rec.ondataavailable = e => {
        console.log("recording...")
        audioChunks.push(e.data);
        console.log(audioChunks)


        let blob = new Blob(audioChunks, { 'type': 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
        let blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        createPlayer(blobURL);
    };
    rec.start(5000)

})
.catch(e => console.log(e));

function createPlayer(blobURL) {
    var audioPlayer = document.createElement("AUDIO");
    audioPlayer.src = blobURL;      
    audioPlayer.setAttribute("id", "player");
    audioPlayer.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
    document.body.appendChild(audioPlayer); 
}
```

Comment: This will still record WebM in Chrome, it just labels in incorrectly as Ogg. If you e.g. transmit this blob to the server you get a WebM file.