# Google cloud speech API not transcription from base64 audio

Tags: node.js, angular, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to use Google cloud speech API, by recording audio in my Angular FrontEnd, converting it to base64, sending it to my Node backend, which does the query to google speech API.

So far I have had no success with it, google only sending me empty results.

You'll see that in order to identify the problem, I'm looping through all possible sampleRate and audio format.

Another thing to note is that testing with Google example audio.raw (found here https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech/tree/master/samples), it works, and I get a transcription.

Here is my front end:

```
 const onSuccess = stream => {
  var options = {
    audioBitsPerSecond: 16000, // NB: I have tried several bitrates, and several audio formats (here, and in the blob creation)
  //   mimeType: 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus'
  }

  this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  this.mediaRecorder.onstop = e => {

    const audio = new Audio();
    const blob = new Blob(this.chunks, { 'type': 'audio/wav' });

    this.chunks.length = 0;
    audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    reader.onloadend = (function () {
      var base64data = reader.result;

      var splited = base64data.substr(base64data.indexOf(',') + 1);

      this.appservice.postAudio(splited).subscribe(res => {
        console.log("MyBuffer: ", res);

      })

    }).bind(this);
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
  };

  this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = e => this.chunks.push(e.data);
};
```

And my Node backend

```
post(req, res) {


    var encoding = ["FLAC", "LINEAR16", "MULAW", "AMR", "AMR_WB", "OGG_OPUS", "SPEEX_WITH_HEADER_BYTE"];
    var sampleRate = ["8000", "12000", "16000", "24000", "44100", "48000"];


    encoding.forEach(elementencoding => {
        sampleRate.forEach(elementrate => {
            const projectId = 'myId';
            const request = {
                "config": {
                    "encoding": elementencoding,
                    "sampleRateHertz": elementrate,
                    "languageCode": "fr-FR"
                },
                "audio": {
                    "content": req.body.base64audio
                }
            };

            const client = new speech.SpeechClient({
                projectId: projectId,
            });
            // Detects speech in the audio file
            client
                .recognize(request)
                .then(data => {
                    console.log("raw data:" + elementencoding + " - " + elementrate + " => ", data[0].results);
                    const response = data[0];
                    const transcription = response.results
                        .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
                        .join('\n');
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error('ERROR:' + elementencoding + ' - ' + elementrate);
                });
        });
    });
}
```

And here is the output I get

```
ERROR:OGG_OPUS - 44100
ERROR:OGG_OPUS - 24000
ERROR:AMR_WB - 44100
ERROR:SPEEX_WITH_HEADER_BYTE - 24000
ERROR:OGG_OPUS - 8000
raw data:LINEAR16 - 48000 =>  []
raw data:LINEAR16 - 44100 =>  []
raw data:LINEAR16 - 12000 =>  []
raw data:LINEAR16 - 16000 =>  []
ERROR:SPEEX_WITH_HEADER_BYTE - 48000
ERROR:AMR_WB - 48000
ERROR:AMR - 24000
ERROR:OGG_OPUS - 12000
ERROR:AMR - 44100
ERROR:SPEEX_WITH_HEADER_BYTE - 8000
ERROR:SPEEX_WITH_HEADER_BYTE - 12000
ERROR:AMR_WB - 8000
ERROR:AMR_WB - 24000
ERROR:OGG_OPUS - 48000
raw data:LINEAR16 - 8000 =>  []
raw data:LINEAR16 - 24000 =>  []
raw data:MULAW - 48000 =>  []
ERROR:AMR - 48000
ERROR:AMR - 12000
ERROR:AMR - 16000
raw data:FLAC - 24000 =>  []
```

Thank you to anybody that could have an idea on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the audio.raw from the Google example works, the issue is likely with the audio you're using. The Speech API is a bit finicky with the audio it accepts. (Mono only for example, see [this article](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig#AudioEncoding)). The problem you're seeing is described in the [troubleshooting section](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/support#troubleshooting) for the Speech API, where it states why you can get an empty response.

I've tested the [mozdevs](https://github.com/mozdevs/MediaRecorder-examples) MediaRecorder examples here to create an audio file and pass that to the Speech API, and it seems the API really doesn't like the format that MediaRecorder creates.

You'll have to convert the audio into something like FLAC or LINEAR16 to get the Speech API to interpret it. Doing some digging I found [this github example](https://github.com/mmig/speech-to-flac), and passing the resulting audio from that to the Speech API I get the correct transcript back from the API.

Comment: Thanks man, I ultimately figured out it came from mozdev mediaRecorder, but didn't find the flac encoder library.
Much appreciated

Comment: Here are some alternatives, for encoding as FLAC or WAV/PCM/LINEAR16: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57837816/2441655